# How would one create a 2-column grid of perfectly square images in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The columns are responsive, so the width changes on different screen sizes. The images are all different sizes and aspect ratios. I can't use the .thumbnail class inherent in bootstrap as it has a lot of styling options I don't want.

Answer (score 10):

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
         <div class="square"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.square {
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    background-image: url('your_img');
    background-size: cover;
}
```

This will try to fit as much of the image as possible into the squares. It will possibly omit some of an image if its got an aspect ratio a long way from 1:1, but is probably your best bet.

Answer (score -3):

Here is how you would do just 2 columns

```
<div class="row show-grid">
      <div class="col-md-6"><img src="" alt="" width="100%" height="auto"></div>
      <div class="col-md-6"><img src="" alt="" width="100%" height="auto"></div>
    </div>
```

Hope this helps.

More info on grids here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: What is the show-grid class? I can't find it mentioned in the Bootstrap documentation.